# Python doesn't detect syntax error

Tags: python, syntax-error, error-detection

I've been trying to sort an array of number using the sort function but I forgot to write parentheses.

```
arr.sort
```

instead of

```
arr.sort()
```

My question is why can't python detect this error and inform me like Java can?
The program kept compiling fine but because I was inputting the numbers in ascending order, the problem wouldn't show up.

Comment: Not a syntax error for python. arr.sort is a function on the type of `arr` . arr.sort is a object pointing to the definition of the function sort().  In java methods do not have this representation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`arr.sort` is syntactically valid. It's just not the syntax you wanted. Syntactically, `arr.sort` is an attribute access expression for the `sort` attribute of whatever `arr` evaluates to; semantically, when `arr` is a list, `arr.sort` evaluates to a method object for `arr`'s `sort` method, so it's perfectly fine at runtime too.

It's kind of like [method references](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13) in Java, but since Python is dynamically typed and has method objects, it doesn't need to go through all the functional interface and poly expression stuff Java 8 had to add to support `list::sort` syntax.

Syntax errors are only for outright invalid syntax.

Comment: How or when can a method object be used?

Comment: @ChrisIoannou: You use it in `arr.sort()`, where unlike in Java, you create a method object for `arr.sort` and then call it with the `()` parentheses. You can also use it for most of the things you'd use method references for in Java.

Answer (score 2):

Because it is not an error.

When you do not include `()` the function (or method) is not called.  Instead it returns the function.

Example:

```
>>> str.encode
<method 'encode' of 'str' objects>
```

In actual practice:

```
import tkinter as tk

def hello():
    print('hello')

tk.Frame()
a = tk.button(text="Press", command=hello)
a.pack()
tk.mainloop()
```

Now if you try it with `command=hello()` then it calls the function without you actually pressing the button.

Comment: "it returns the type" - what? That's not true.

Comment: I don't think the random `tkinter` example really adds anything to this answer.  It was fine before

Comment: @chrisz  It does because it adds an example to how it is *not* a syntax error

Answer (score 1):

The reason why Python can't detect this type of error is because Python is dynamically typed, whereas Java is statically typed.

When you say `a = arr.sort`, python assigns the function to `a`. Now you can do `a()` and it will run arr.sort. This is a totally valid thing to do in Python, and since we don't tell it ahead of time what `a` should be, it can't know whether you meant `a` to be a function or a sorted list... it just trusts you know what you're doing.

Java, on the other hand, is statically typed: You tell it ahead of time what `a` should be. Therefore, when you accidentally leave off parens, it says "that's a function, not a list like you said it would be".

---

If you use an IDE like PyCharm, it will tell you lots of warnings along these lines:

`self.function` shows:

> Statement seems to have no effect and can be replaced with function call to have an effect

but the moment we assign it:

`a = self.function` it has an effect and this cannot be detected.